# location props in gatsby is not defined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, gatsby

I am trying to use location props in my gastby page :
I am passing props in my Link in
pages/index.js:

```
 <Link state={{eventID: event.id}}  to={`/date/${event.name}`}>
  </Link>
```

pages/date/[dateId]/index.js:

```
const DateWithId = ({location},props) => {
    const { state = {} } = location
    const { eventID} = state
...}
```

eventually I get an error Parsing error: Identifier 'location' has already been declareded :
[image]

Comment: Are you able to access the variable globally? You may not need to specify `location` as a function parameter, it seems like you should already have access to it

Comment: thank you i was defining another location variable !

Comment: Glad I could help! I'll post my comment as a short answer so we can close this out :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should have the `location` variable already defined, it is likely in the global scope so you don't need to pass it as a parameter to the function. Try just using the variable and see if that works.